# how can I show my likes.map() correctly with active likeUserConnected?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, array.prototype.map, social-likes

So I create an Table Likes and I want to create a change of like when the user connected has already liked with a red Heart. When a post is not liked by an user connecter the heart is empty.

When I had to map() my table Likes to have the id of the userliked and see if the user connected have liked the post, it work but if there is "0 likes" the heart doesn't appear and if there is "+2 likes" I have the red heart and the empty heart. My requeste doesn't work. Here is a exemple on picture: [image: 0 likes]

[image: +2 likes]

And here is my request :

```
<div className="home-icon-post"   onClick={handleLikes}>
           
          {
            !isEmpty(likesData[0]) &&
            likesData
              .map((likes) => {
                if (likes.id === userData.id && likes.idComment === comment.idObject ) return <div key={likes.idObject}> 
                <div>
                  
                 {  
                    <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className={"heartFull"} icon={["fa","heart"]} />
                    
                    </div>
                  } 
                  </div>
                </div>
          else if (likes.id !== userData.id && likes.idComment === comment.idObject  ) {
           return <FontAwesomeIcon  className={"iconEmpty" } icon={["fa","heart"]} /> 
          } 
          else return null
              }) 
            }
               </div>
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: I presume theres no heart showing because on intitial state likesData[0] is empty and the empty heart is in the map so it'll just return an empty div.

Comment: Yes but if I out the empty heart to the map() it send me an empty heart everywhere :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems  was on the map.(), Somebody give me the solution and here is the answer:

Here is the variable before the return on react:

```
  const isLiked = () => {
  return Array.from(likesData).filter(likes => likes.id === userData.id && likes.idComment === comment.idObject).length > 0 
 }
```

And the call of variable on return react:

```
    <div className="home-icon-post" onClick={() => handleLikes()} > 
            {
             <FontAwesomeIcon className={`${isLiked(comment.idObject) ? "heartFull" : "heartEmpty"}`}  icon={["fa","heart"]} />
            }
            
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change onClick handler on div as

```
<div className="home-icon-post" onClick={() => handleLikes()}>
```

Comment: It can't work with onClick because every like is manage with my database